# Can we access active users in between date range in wso2 identity server?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Im trying to get the active users who were logged in past one week. but there only one API which gives currently active sessions(users). is there any way to get all the active user Id or user count who were logged-in in one week ?

I tried API /sessions api which gave me only currently active users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using IS-6.0.0, this option can be used.

1. Enable the following event handler in deployment.toml file to update the last logon time of the users when they log into applications.

```
[identity_mgt.events.schemes.identityUserMetadataMgtHandler.properties]
enable=true
```

It will update the login timestamp in `http://wso2.org/claims/identity/lastLogonTime` claim.

2. Use SCIM API to filter out users who has last logon time between given two time stamps.

Sample CURL:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://localhost:9443/scim2/Users?filter=urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User.lastLogonTime+ge+1674065031350+and+urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User.lastLogonTime+le+1674065770177&count=10&startIndex=1' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4='
```

NOTE: This filtering will work only when pagination parameters are given.
`filter=urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User.lastLogonTime+ge+1674065031350+and+urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User.lastLogonTime+le+1674065770177` -> means that filter the users who has last logon time greater than 1674065031350 and less than 1674065770177

Comment: Thank you @Anuradha Karunarathna. it worked for me. But I also wanted how many number of time the user logged into the system.

Comment: Then you have to write a custom event handler https://ganganichamika.medium.com/write-a-custom-event-handler-using-the-wso2-identity-server-eventing-framework-caa5dc9da8a3 which is subscribed to `POST_AUTHENTICATION ` event, from that handler update the user login count. You need to add a custom claim to maintain this property. Then map the custom claim to a new scim claim to retrieve the login count in the scim user payload